# can we create commenting system sending notification to first five replied comment or not of parent comment?

Tags: php, tree, notifications, sendmail

I have php function for sending single notification mail for parent comment.But I want to send first five replied comments notification to parent comment.Please let me know if any idea or php code.

Comment: Share your code snippet. Show us where you are stuck ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`If ($count_replies % 5 == 0) sendMail();`

Something like this. :^ )

Oh, forget an answer. And the answer is: Yes, you can.

Comment: some what got idea of your code sectus,but can you provide me detail about the above code?

Comment: @pramodhkumar , what details? I didn't see your DB, code or something else.

Comment: sorry i restricted to provide code,but logic is like tree node. The commenting system like disqus,where main comment id is added as 0 and parent id is added to sub comment id table.i hope English is understandable to you

Comment: @pramodhkumar, count replies, if it will divisible by five you can send a mail.

Comment: ok thank you sectus,i will get the count of replies of parent id and try to implement your logic.

Comment: @pramodhkumar, glad to hear it :^ )